# Switch between two page message and refresh button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

In my web application when user switch from one page to other then

1.Message if it takes more than say 5 seconds.

2.Refresh button if it takes more than 10 seconds.

Requirement for display message:
A read document (XML file), where a page is called, it will pull "Did You know" + specific content of that page and display.

Is it possible?Or am I going to wrong direction?